# how to add 1000 row to table with values auto create

Tags: mysql

I want to add new row to my table with 1000 loop with one `mysql transaction`

```sql
INSERT INTO tbl_palletmaster (PalletID) 
VALUES (RIGHT(CONCAT('00000000',LAST_INSERT_ID()),8));
```

Comment: which mysql version?

Comment: Can you not use an auto increment field for PalletID ?

Comment: MariaDB 10.4.8 is mysql db version

Comment: palletid must computer caculation value, It same (CONCAT ('99', RIGHT(CONCAT('00000000',LAST_INSERT_ID()),8)))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can have a generated serial numbers to insert,

```
INSERT INTO tbl_palletmaster (PalletID)
SELECT 
    (RIGHT(CONCAT('00000000',@row := @row + 1),8))
FROM 
    (SELECT 0 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 2 UNION ALL SELECT 3 UNION ALL SELECT 4 UNION ALL SELECT 5 UNION ALL SELECT 6 UNION ALL SELECT 7 UNION ALL SELECT 8 UNION ALL SELECT 9) t,
    (SELECT 0 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 2 UNION ALL SELECT 3 UNION ALL SELECT 4 UNION ALL SELECT 5 UNION ALL SELECT 6 UNION ALL SELECT 7 UNION ALL SELECT 8 UNION ALL SELECT 9) t2, 
    (SELECT 0 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 2 UNION ALL SELECT 3 UNION ALL SELECT 4 UNION ALL SELECT 5 UNION ALL SELECT 6 UNION ALL SELECT 7 UNION ALL SELECT 8 UNION ALL SELECT 9) t3, 
    (SELECT @row:=0) numbers;
```